# Python - hash of hash of hash perl equivalent

Tags: python, defaultdict

Experts,

I am coming from Perl background and very much used to using nested hash structures like `$row{dept}{owner}{name}{access} = "\\server\path";`

Tried doing similar in Python using,

```
row = collections.defaultdict(dict)
```

`row[dept][owner]` works but cannot do `row[dept][owner][name][access]`

Tried string concat to merge 4 values into 2 like, `row[dept_owner][name_access]` but that does not solve the purpose. Say, if I directly want to find keys/values for `row["IT"]["John Smith"]["Reporting"]`

Should I improve on `defaultdict` or there is another/better way to do this, really appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: You can do this with the existing `defaultdict`. Please see the accepted answer of the linked question for details; the other answers there also contain useful information.

Comment: The problem is that you are creating a `defaultdict` that as values creates regular `dict`. You get the solution in the "This question already has an answer here:" link. Anyway, it seems that you may be using wrong tool for the job. I don't know your case, but seems that you may want to use ORM like PeeWee or just a few well named classes linked between. Getting deep into nested dicts with literal keywords is like asking for trouble :)